# Correct way of updating Property so that loading doesn't stop UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

Sorry about the headline but it was the best I could come up with. Let me explain my problem: I have a WPF application that has a Menu looking much like your standard top menu that only takes up 5% of the screen. Click a menu item and the view below changes. The menu control is home-brewed because of reasons: Dynamic changes to menu-items, weird UI that doesn't fit existing controls, etc.

The menu changing view part is done using a ContentControl that binds to a "CurrentMenuView" property. When a menu item is clicked, this happens (pseudo-code):

```
private async void Button_Pressed(...)
{
   await MakeSomeVisualMenuChanges();
   CurrentMenuView = new CarsView();
   await MakeSomOtherStuff();
}
```

The problem is that some views take some time to load, which makes the other steps happen slow also. I'd like to start loading the "CarsView" but at the same time (not after) continue with the other changes. So the user can see stuff happening.

I can solve this by using Task.Run() but that seems wrong as it puts stuff in a different context.

What is the correct / better way of dealing with this?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all answers, as I expected this is not easy to explain. Let me try with a simple example:

MainWindows.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp32.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="300" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Content="Click" Click="Button_Click"  />
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Height="200"  Content="{Binding PageContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Bottom" Width="300" x:Name="BottomText" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-Behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp32
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BottomText.Text = "AndNowforSomethingCompletelyDifferent";
            PageContent = new UserControl1();
        }

        private object pageContent;
        public object PageContent
        {
            get => pageContent;
            set
            {
                pageContent = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(PageContent)));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
}
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp32.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CtrlTextBlock" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl1.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp32
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            CtrlTextBlock.Text = "Loaded";
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Init();
        }
    }
}
```

So this is stripped from async etc and just showing the issue. When the button is pressed, the UserControl1 is loaded but it takes 2 seconds to load. Until then, the text in the "BottomText" element remains unset.

As I said before, I can solve this by doing something like this in the button click:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BottomText.Text = "AndNowforSomethingCompletelyDifferent";
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => PageContent = new UserControl1()));
}
```

But not sure that is the way to go. So the basic issue here, is that a ContentControl is bound to a property and setting that property might take some time. While that is loading I don't want execution in the MainWindow to be halted (I want the BottomText element to display "AndNowforSomethingCompletelyDifferent" immediately).

Comment: Task.Run won't help because it would create UI elements in a different thread than the UI thread. Besides that, we can't tell what a correct or better way of loading your views is, because we don't know them.

Comment: There might be 2 problems: "heavy" views with lots of resources or user code hanging on `Loaded` etc events. For the first one, you could try pre-loading your controls/resources in advance (search for that on Google and StackOverflow). For the second one, make the event handlers `async` and try to decouple your custom logic from the UI thread.

Comment: So loading `CarsView()` takes long to load for example? If that is the case, there is maybe a lot to do, or a lot of data that comes with the constructor, right? You could decouple the loading of this data (or the heavy methods) from the constructor and trigger them from an event and do them async. While this is done, show some indicator in the GUI, but you can do the next thing right away.

Comment: You already have ```await``` in there twice.  I'm confused why you don't want to use ```Task.Run```.  Are those awaits not asynchronous? "but that seems wrong as it puts stuff in a different context"  What do you mean here?  In WPF you can't load the UI in a different context; it will throw an error.  Should you use a task to load the UI resources in a difference context? Yes, absolutely; that's what it's meant for.

Comment: As Clemens mentioned, UI controls have thread affinity. Data does not. I would usually do viewmodel first for this sort of thing and template a viewmodel into ui. Newing up a viewmodel and it's data could be done on a background thread. This is the first thing you should consider. Oh. That and not reading 100,000 records at a time.

Comment: The other "changes"? What kind of changes are you doing in your methods? As others have mentioned, you can only modify the UI on a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that simulates 3 seconds of loading... It's not an extremely complex UI and binding to complex `DataTemplates`, especially nested, can slow things a bit but normally the drag comes from pulling the data.

The trick is having a clever UI that keeps things moving but also lets the user know it's waiting on something else to continue.  The infamous loading bar for example... Not that I would use that exact process but that's the right idea.

*Note and disclaimer: I almost despise code behind unless it's in a custom control of some type; never in the view.  I always prefer MVVM and using a ViewModel for binding; but not to build or control the UI only for the data the UI uses.  All that said because this example is none of that.  I simply made the controls on the view and put the code behind for answering this question, with example, as simple as possible.*

#### The View

```
<Window x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="500"
        Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToggleButton x:Name="menuButton"
                      Content="Menu"
                      Click="MenuButton_Click" />

        <!--I do not recommend binding in the view like this... Make a custom control that does this properly.-->
        <Grid x:Name="menu"
              Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=menuButton}"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Background="Wheat">
            <StackPanel x:Name="menuItems">
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
                <TextBlock Text="simulated...." />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="menuLoading">
                <TextBlock Text="Loading..."
                           FontSize="21" />
                <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"
                             Height="3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### Code Behind the View

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Question_Answer_WPF_App
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();

        private Task SimulateLoadingResourcesAsnyc() => Task.Delay(3000);

        private async void MenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            menuItems.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            menuLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            await SimulateLoadingResourcesAsnyc();

            menuItems.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            menuLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated. I have added some example that tries to clarify my issue.

Comment: In your example it should never take 2 seconds to load that new control. If assigning content is taking that long then rather fix it here I would look for the bottleneck there. I also recommend Dependency Properties instead of NotifyPropertyChanged since you're on the UI and part. of a DependencyObject anyway. You are correct, doing that to assign content is just hackery to make it work but the Content being assigned is the problem IMO. I just don't think it should ever take that long and if so the new content should have the asynchronous methods added so that it renders immediately.